# Swagger yaml instead of OpenApi annotations

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to use /static/custom-openapi.yaml file for show in Swagger url for my SpringBoot project, but I cannot make that the content of yaml shows in Swagger doc. Instead of that, It seems that the Swagger UI that is shown is the autogenerated. I tried using **springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs** and **springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false** but not working. And when I use **springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/custom-openapi.yaml** I'm getting a 404 Whitelabel Error Page.

Thanks.